# Find files containing multiple words where the order of the words does not matter

Tags: find

I have a huge folder with a lot of subfolders where I would like to search for a folder that contains three words. Note that the folder name needs to have all three words, but the order of the words does not matter.

Example: I want to find folders containing the words `APE`, `Banana` and `Tree`.

```
find folder -name '*APE*Banana*Tree*'
```

However, this command will consider the order of the words, while this is not of interest and I want to find any folder with those words in any order.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use 3 `-name`s:

```
find folder -name '*APE*' -name '*Banana*' -name '*Tree*' -type d
```

Beware that like any time you use wildcards in the `-name` pattern that it may miss files whose name contains sequence of characters not forming valid characters in the user's locale.

With `zsh`:

```
set -o extendedglob # best in ~/.zshrc
print -rC1 -- **/(*Banana*~^*APE*~^*Tree*)(ND/)
```

The `/` [glob qualifier](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) being the equivalent of `find`'s `-type d` to select files of type `d`irectory.

With `ksh93`:

```
FIGNORE='@(.|..)'
set -o globstar
set -- ~(N)**/@(*Banana*&*APE*&*Tree*)/
(($# == 0)) || printf '%s\n' "$@"
```

`ksh93` has no glob qualifiers, but appending a `/` to the globs restricts the expansion to files that are directories or symlinks to directories.

With `bash`:

```
shopt -s globstar dotglob nullglob extglob
set -- **/!(!(*Banana*)|!(*APE*)|!(*Tree*))/
(($# == 0)) || printf '%s\n' "$@"
```

Same note as for `ksh93` above about the trailing `/`.

Where:

- `D`, `FIGNORE`, `dotglob` makes sure hidden files are also reported (like `find` does)
- `N`, `~(N)`, `nullglob` makes the glob expand to nothing instead of causing an error or expand to itself when there's no match
- `globstar` makes `ksh93`/`bash` understand zsh's `**/` recursive globbing operator.
- `(x~^Y)`, `@(X&Y)`, `!(!(X)|!(Y))` being [three approaches in the respective shells to match files that match both patterns](/a/287175).

Comment: Of course: find folder -name ... is recursive. It will find all directory entries (files and directories) inside any sub-directory. A maxdepth or prune is required to limit this